# Issues running commands in terminal

Tags: c

I have this assignment for Operating Systems, the code won't run in MAC terminal, I keep getting an issue that says, "[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvMky.png)". Is there any help I can get on this issue?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// These two functions will run concurrently
void* print_i(void *ptr)
{
    printf("I am in i\n");
}
    void* print_j(void *ptr)
{
    printf("I am in j\n");
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    int rc1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, print_i, NULL);
    int rc2 = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, print_j, NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't when you run the program, the problem happens when you build the source code. And the problem is quite clearly explained in the text (which you really should copy-paste *as text* into your question): You have two functions declared to return something, and yet they don't return anything.

Comment: What's the error? You haven't actually asked a question here.

Comment: On another note, once you get the code to build cleanly, it will probably not work as you expect. The problem is that your process will most likely end before the threads even get a chance to run. You must wait for the threads to finish before exiting the process.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code? The image you've shown is two warnings when you try to compile it.

Answer (score -1):

The keyword void (not a pointer) means "nothing" in C. This is consistent.

As you noted, void* means "pointer to anything" in languages that support raw pointers (C and C++). This means you need to return something.

This is the reason why you get this type of warning.

If you return someting, like return 0; warnings disapear.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// These two functions will run concurrently
void* print_i(void *ptr)
{
    printf("I am in i\n");
    return 0;
}
    void* print_j(void *ptr)
{
    printf("I am in j\n");
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    int rc1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, print_i, NULL);
    int rc2 = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, print_j, NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

You can learn more about it here:

https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create

Comment: Thank you very much for putting this into perspective for me! Wish I could upvote you but I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: @BennyBen, I hope it helped you. No problem. :)